# how to get minimum sum in the list of double values which inside the list

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

i have list of list `[[1.2], [2.0], [20.0], [10.0], [50.0], [0.5, 50.0], [0.5, 20.0], [0.5, 10.0], [0.5, 1.2], [0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 2.0]]`

i want to get minimum sum amount of inner list as output (without using loops) In java program.
output should be :  [0.5, 0.5]

Comment: Why do you want to avoid loop ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Arrays.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
double[][] values = {{1.2}, {2.0}, ...};
Arrays.stream(values).min(Comparator.comparingDouble(t -> Arrays.stream(t).sum())).get()
```

The `Stream<double[][]>.min()` function returns an [`Optional<double[]>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). This optional will be empty if values is empty. Than you need to check for the existence of a minimum with `Optional<double[]>.isPresent()` before you can call `Optional<double[]>.get()`.

Comment: just a sidenote, when declaring arrays, you can omit the `new double[][]`and `new double[]` completly.

Comment: @Lino Thx :), I totally forgot about this. I updated my answer this way.